# Steam аутентификация во Flutter

Tags: flutter, openid

интересна возможность аутентификация через Steam в приложениях Flutter с возвратом steamid.

Comment: нам тоже интересна подобная возможность

Comment: Что-то уже у Вас получилось сделать или Вы это записали здесь что бы не забыть?

Comment: @V.March Тестировал данный вариант.https://github.com/Hexer10/steam_login К сожалению не сработал. Из ответа вариант еще не тестил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

С начало необходимо зарегистрироваться в [Steam Web API](https://steamcommunity.com/dev/revokekey).

С помощью плагинов [openid_client](https://pub.dev/packages/openid_client) и [url_launcher](https://pub.dev/packages/url_launcher), будет как-то так (Я, не проверял, возможно нужно будет доработать, смотрите документацию этих плагинов и [Steam API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API).):

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'package:openid_client/openid_client.dart';
import 'package:openid_client/openid_client_io.dart';
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart';

void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
    body: HomePage(),
  )));
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Center(
      child: FutureBuilder(
          future: authenticate(Uri.parse("http://steamcommunity.com/openid"), "id", "key"),
          builder: (context, snap) {
            if (snap.connectionState == ConnectionState.none &&
                snap.hasData == null) {
              //print('snapshot data is: ${snap.data}');
              return Container();
            }
            return ListView.builder(
              itemCount: snap.data.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                var data = snap.data[index];
                return Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    // Widget to display the list of data
                  ],
                );
              },
            );
          }),
    );
  }

  authenticate(Uri uri, String clientId, String clientSecret) async {
    // create the client
    var issuer = await Issuer.discover(uri);
    var client = new Client(issuer, clientId, clientSecret);

    // create a function to open a browser with an url
    urlLauncher(String url) async {
      if (await canLaunch(url)) {
        await launch(url, forceWebView: true);
      } else {
        throw 'Could not launch $url';
      }
    }

    // create an authenticator
    var authenticator = new Authenticator(client, urlLancher: urlLauncher);

    // starts the authentication
    var c = await authenticator.authorize();

    // close the webview when finished
    closeWebView();

    // return the user info
    return await c.getUserInfo();
  }
}

List<String> scopes = new List<String>();
```

---

Либо использовать [Steam Web API](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetPlayerSummaries_.28v0001.29) через вызов и обработку в удобном для вас формате: `http://api.steampowered.com/<interface name>/<method name>/v<version>/?key=<api key>&format=<format>`